# NumPy arrays with flexible dtype can be compared with == but not np.equal

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I was hoping to be able to see if two structured arrays were equal using `np.equal` so that I can specify the output array. However, this doesn't work! To my surprise though, using `==` works just fine and gives the expected results. There is also the quirk that `np.equal` and friends return a `NotImplemented` object (see https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2091) so it took awhile to find this bug...

```
import numpy as np
dt = np.dtype([('A', int), ('B', int)])
a = np.zeros(10, dtype=dt)
b = np.ones(10, dtype=dt)
print(np.equal(a, a)) # returns NotImplemented
print(np.equal(a, b)) # returns NotImplemented
print(a == a)         # returns array of 10 Trues
print(a == b)         # returns array of 10 Falses
```

A workaround in my case is to view the array differently, since I know all of the entries in the structure will be the same dtype I can do the following:

```
A = a.view(a.dtype[0]).reshape(-1, len(a.dtype))
B = b.view(b.dtype[0]).reshape(-1, len(b.dtype))
np.equal(A, B).all(axis=1)
```

However this causes me some problems as that I can only really efficiently preallocate the output array from `all` but not the `equal` so it is not optimal. Also, I would just like to understand how `equal` and `==` are different, I really thought they were the same...

In case it matters, I am running:
Python: 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
NumPy: 1.8.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a == b` translates to `a.__eq__(b)`

```
In [377]: a.__eq__??
Type:        method-wrapper
String form: <method-wrapper '__eq__' of numpy.ndarray object at 0xa2095d8>
Definition:  a.__eq__(self, *args, **kwargs)
Docstring:   Return self==value.
```

`np.equal` is a `ufunc` (`equal(x1, x2[, out])`)

Both are implemented in C, so it would take some digging to see how they differ.

Since they are, apparently, implemented independently, the difference could arise from any number of implementation details.

For example, one might compare the elements down to the `np.void` level, and the other down to the `tuple` level.

```
In [404]: np.equal(a[1],b[1])
Out[404]: NotImplemented

In [405]: a[1].item()==b[1].item()
Out[405]: False
```

---

I assume, that by `working with given output`, you mean something equivalent to the `ufunc` `out` parameter.

I wonder if the following will do the trick:

```
c = np.empty((10,), dtype=bool)
c[:] = a==b    # or c[...]=
c[:] = a==a
```

I can't guarantee that there this won't involve a temporary array.  BUt various functions that take `out` and are coded purely in Python use this method.

Comment: I always imagined that `ndarray.__eq__` and `numpy.equal` eventually called the same internal "equals" function... but yes, I realized that the flexible dtype values could be compared field-wise or the opaque data backing them. I did not expect anything besides (not) equal to work - although other comparisons do work (with the operators, not the ufuncs) and work field-wise, not with the opaque data (tested with negative numbers).

Comment: So... is there a way to use `__eq__` with a given output? Or is there a way to make `equals` work with the flexible data type and no temporary output?

Comment: Your suggestion does in fact work (although it does create a temporary). My testing shows it be slightly faster than my workaround and it works in the general case (if it was is a non-flexible or flexible type).

Comment: I recently was looking at Numpy's source code and found out that it first attempts the ufunc for all comparisons then (for EQ and NE) it says `The ufunc does not support void/structured types, so these need to be handled specifically. Only a few cases are supported.` where it then tries a void-specific comparison (for EQ and NE only) then eventually a string comparison (for all operators).